# Добавить новую версию программы в Play Market

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-play-console

мы выложили программу на гугл плей маркет. Теперь нужно практически полностью изменить дизайн и добавить много нового функционала. Вопрос в том, если  писать эту программу заново (начисто), сохранив имя пакета и подписав его тем же ключом, примет ли Google ее, когда мы сделаем обновление, или нам нужно править эту версию и переписать ее? Изменений настолько много, что проще заново все писать включая логику.

Comment: на Stack Overflow на русском вопросы принято задавать **только на русском языке.** Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь Stack Overflow на английском.

Answer (score 0):

Примет. Google Play смотрит только на ключ подписки и имя пакета.